# AppCompat ToolBar popupTheme not used when multi selection active

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

In styles.xml I'm styling the popup theme of the overflow menu in the toolbar:

```
<style name="ToolbarOverflowMenuStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

That works as intended but if I do a multi selection in a recycler view (list) the popup theme background color turns from white to yellow (the color of the toolbar). I have no idea why that is since it has the right color if the multi-selection isn't active.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Styling of the toolbar:

```
<style name="PostToolbarStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/lightGray2</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/defaultTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/defaultTextColor</item>
</style>
```

And this is how I set the toolbar in the layout xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarOverflowMenuStyle"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>
```

How the popup theme looks like (correctly) when multi-selection is not active:
[image: Displayed correctly]

And here how is being displayed (wrongly) when multi-select is active:
[image]

Comment: Probably off-topic: **DO NOT** use `background` or `backgroundTint` in *themes* because they will be applied to every child of a widget (every item instead of total background). Define `popupBackground` or `colorBackground`.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I've applied those changes to the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its [**Menu**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) -`ActionMode` you see your default `OptionsMenu` popUp background is the white, and the default contextual Menu for your app is the Yellow in your case. When you enter into multi-selection a ActionMode is triggered to handle the itemClick and what have you, and since you know how CAB works.

if you want to maintain the same white background in your `setMultiChoiceModeListener` override `onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)` and use `getCustomView().setBackgroundColor(Color.White);`

**Edit**: *addressing comment*

This is what i mean in your `onPrePareActionMode()`

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    //the mode parameter is your CAB, so call that on it
    mode.getCustomView().setBackgroundColor(Color.White);
}
```

Hope its helpful

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I tried to apply it but had no luck getting it to work yet. I have  
`code` 
private class ItemMultiSelectorCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {  @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
`code`

Comment: Sorry had to add another comment because I can only edit a comment for 5 min:

Thanks for that hint. I tried to apply it but had no luck getting it to work yet. I have this code:

`code` 
private class ItemMultiSelectorCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {  @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {

MenuItem moveMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_move_multi_documents);
moveMenuItem.setVisible(!isFolderInSelection && !isDraftFolder);

return true;
}
`code`

Cannot use the getCustomView() method anywhere in there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you Try editing you style with this property, selectableItemBackground

```
  <style name="ToolbarOverflowMenuStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/white</item>
<item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item></style>
```

Had a similar problem with SwitchCompat and the solution was in one of the properties itself. Also this blog helped a lot .  http://blog.mohitkanwal.com/blog/2015/03/07/styling-material-toolbar-in-android/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. unfortunately this didn't have any effect on the popupTheme toolbar color. It seems like the popup toolbar (while multi-select active) uses the same style settings like the regular toolbar styling.