# android:popupBackground not working for context menus

Tags: android, xml, android-contextmenu

Why does my `styles.xml` code successfully change the background colour of my actionbar overflow menu, but fail to change the background colour of the context menu in my app?

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/DarkActionBar</item> -->

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomMenuTextAppearance</item>

</style>

<!-- Popup Menu Background Color styles -->
<!-- <style name="MyPopupMenu"  parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow"> -->
<!-- <style name="MyPopupMenu"  parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu"> -->
<style name="MyPopupMenu"  parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/dark_gray</item> 
</style>
<!-- Popup Menu Text Color styles -->
<style name="MyCustomMenuTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I've been stuck on this for a couple of hours and none of the solutions on SO for similar questions have worked for me.

If it helps, here is my Java code where the context menu is created:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
            (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    String selectedWord = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();
    menu.setHeaderTitle(selectedWord);

    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.shopping_list_name_context, menu);
}
```

And, for completeness, here is my context menu xml, `shopping_list_name_context.xml`:

```
<item android:id="@+id/rename_shopping_list"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
      android:title="@string/rename_shopping_list" />

<item android:id="@+id/empty_shopping_list"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
      android:title="@string/empty_shopping_list" />

<item android:id="@+id/delete_shopping_list"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
      android:title="@string/delete_shopping_list" />
```

And, as requested, here is an excerpt of my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<supports-screens       
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name_short"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:largeHeap="true" >
```

Comment: Can you post your AppManifest.xml please?

Comment: OK, have now added the relevant part of it.

Comment: Check this stackoverflow [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526667/appcompat-toolbar-popuptheme-not-used-when-multi-selection-active/30633124#30633124) .

Comment: I had to resort to changing the foreground colour instead, but I've had a lot of new answers since then, so I'll check them out now...

Comment: @Heyyou I've tried all the suggestions, but none of them worked. I think a few of the answerers thought it is the overflow menu I am trying to change, when I'm actually trying to change the contextual menu that shows after long-pressing on a view (in this case, a custom text view).

Comment: Have you found a solution to this question, indeed no existing answers solves this.

Answer (score 2):

Below is code for set background in context menu and it works like charm.

In styles.xml file put below code:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

  <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it only changes the overflow menu bg colour - not the context menu bg colour.

Comment: Hey bro, you put only one single line itemBackground in style that i have to update in my answer and remove all other lines and it works like a charm, i have tested it

Comment: Can you tell me when you have updated the code in your answer and I will try again.

Comment: as shown above i have add android:itemBackground in appliaction style.Just put one line and check it.It works i have testd in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite the actionModeBackground like this:

```
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/context_menu</item>
```

possible duplicate question: [Override context menu colors in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604562/override-context-menu-colors-in-android)

Comment: I've added that to my `<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">...</style>` element (and created **drawable-nodpi/context_menu.xml**) but I'm afraid it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
<item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Cheers, but I get this error for the second line: `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'popupBackground'.`

Comment: what is your taargetSdkVersion?

Comment: Target sdk version is 14.

Comment: remove this line: <item name="popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>

Answer (score 0):

In your app bar XML:

```
app:popupTheme="@style/MyCustomOverflowTheme"
```

Then in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyCustomOverflowTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT**

```
app:popupTheme="@style/MyCustomOverflowTheme"
```

Should go as your Toolbar or ActionBar property, e.g:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    app:theme="@style/MyCustomToolBarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/MyCustomOverflowTheme"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you clarify where the `app:popupTheme="@style/MyCustomOverflowTheme"` line should go?

Comment: Just noticed your edit. The context menu is not being shown from a Toolbar or ActionBar, but by long-pressing on a custom TextView. I have tried adding `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and `app:popupTheme="@style/MyCustomOverflowTheme"` to the custom TextView in the xml, but I just get `error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'popupTheme' in package 'com.example.myapp'`.

Comment: You got an error because TextView can't use this attribute.

Comment: Thank you, yes. Result is that it is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put "android:actionModeBackground" in your ActionBar theme ?

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- main theme -->
    .....
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>

    <!-- if you're using Toolbar you have to put this -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
         .....
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/theme_ambiance_dark</item>
        .....
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using "contextPopupMenuStyle" instead of "popupMenuStyle".

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked, ended-up doing the following, inspired by an answer here: [How to change the background color of the options menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu)

Note that for context menu, setting transparent has no effect, need to set a background on the parent.

This is working on Android 13, not tested yet on any other platforms.

```
@Override public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    //  Option menu!
    if (name.equals("androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ListMenuItemView") && parent.getParent() instanceof FrameLayout)
    {
        ((View) parent.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    }

    //  Context menu!
    if (name.equals("com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView") && parent.getParent() instanceof FrameLayout)
    {
        parent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.special_background);
    }
    return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
}
```